# Brownian motion, correlation coefficient, expectation function

Tags: expected-value, brownian-motion, correlation

Let $\{B(t);t≥0\}$ be a Wiener process (Brownian motion) with $\sigma^2=1$. Define the stochastic process Let $\{X(t); t>0\}$ by

$X(t)=e^{-t}B(e^{2t})$

Let $Y=X(1/2)-X(0)$, and $Z=X(1)-X(1/2)$.

I am tasked to find the correlation coefficient, and among other things i need to find $E(YZ)$, which I don't know how to do. I know that $E(Y)=E(Z)=0$, and I understand how to find $E(Y^2)$ and $E(Z^2)$ by using

$V(Y)=E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2=E(Y^2)$,

and

$V(X(1/2)-X(0))=V(X(1/2))+V(X(0))-2C(X(1/2),X(0))$, and vice versa for $V(Z)$, but I can't seem to understand how to find $E(YZ)$ specifically. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think it should follow from $E[B_sB_t]=s\wedge t$.

Comment: @nejimban, I don't recognize that expression. Any links?

Comment: I meant $E[B_sB_t]=\min(s,t)$. This is the covariance kernel of the standard Brownian motion and it is quite easy to compute: suppose $s<t$, then $E[B_sB_t]=E[B_s(B_s+B_t-B_s)]=E[B_s^2]+E[B_s]E[B_{t-s}]=s=\min(s,t)$.

Comment: @nejimban, thanks, that works.